# What exactly does mobx-react-lite's "useLocalStore" hook do, and why is it (only sometimes) needed?

Tags: mobx, mobx-react, mobx-react-lite

Within the [mobx-react documentation](https://mobx-react.js.org) there are variations in how stores are created. For example, on the [React Context](https://mobx-react.js.org/recipes-context) page:

In the first code sample, the store is instantiated with useLocalStore:

```
  const store = useLocalStore(createStore)
```

In the second code sample, the stores are initiated by directly "newing" the stores":

```
  counterStore: new CounterStore(),
  themeStore: new ThemeStore(),
```

By inference, the first is a *"local"* store (and thus needs useLocalStore), and the second is a *"global"* store and thus doesn't. However, **it is not clear why this is, and what the subsequent differnce in behaviour is**.

Why is `useLocalStore` not needed in second example, and what difference does this make to the behavior of the stores and mobx within React?

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 15):

OK, I found the answer. `useLocalStore` turns a javascript literal into a store with observable properties. This is not needed if a store is created from a class object with observable attributes.

Thanks to @freddyc for [the answer](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-docz/issues/66)

Comment: Freddyc's answer is no longer available. Can you point us to a different source?

Comment: Please see answer by `M K` since `useLocalStore()` is deprecated function

Answer (score 4):

`useLocalStore` has been deprecated in favor of `useLocalObservable`, see [here](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-lite#uselocalstoret-sinitializer---t-source-s-t-deprecated).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It would fit more as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Links from the question are no longer valid, mobx-react docs are now here:
https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html

```js
useLocalObservable(initializer, annotations)
```

is just a shorthand for:

```js
useState(() => observable(initializer(), annotations, {autoBind: true}))[0]
```

`useLocalStore` is almost the same, but it was deprecated because it wasn't as practical.

### Why is this needed?

`useState()` is the main way to store a variable in React.

`observable({...})` is the main way to create observable objects in Mobx.

And when using Mobx+React you'll often need the `useState + observable` combo, so it is nice to have a shorthand.

### When is it not needed?

If you are using a class to create your store then you don't need the `observable` wrapper and you can simply do:

```js
const myStore = useState(() => new MyStore())[0];
```

If you are using React class components you can save the store on a class field.

```js
class MyComponent
{
   myStore = new MyStore();

   render() {...}
}
```

---

Bonus tip:

Why do we use `useState` for memorizing values instead of `useMemo`?

`useMemo` is meant to be used more like a cache for performance optimization, rather than for storing app state.